# Firewall missing from AWS MarketPlace Centos7 image

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, centos7, amazon-ami, firewalld

I am using this [image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW?ref=cns_srchrow) from AWS MarketPlace.
The Problem is that centos 7 is supposed to come with `firewalld` instead of iptables.
But `firewalld` is not installed on it but `iptables` is installed. Why is that. What other changes are there for this particular image that centos is providing that are supposed to be on regular centos 7 images.

Comment: You can always install firewalld yourself.

Comment: Yes that I can do. But I want to understand why doesn't it comes with the image when it's supposed to be or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: And what other such differences are there.

Comment: @SaadMasood An addition is of course already mentioned in the highlights *"Starting with CentOS-7 we now include cloud-init support in all CentOS AMI's"*  and you can of-course simply check what is actually installed once you have deployed an image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get exactly the image the [description](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW?ref=cns_srchrow) says:

> ... built with a minimal profile ... The image contains just enough packages to run within AWS, bring up an SSH Server and allow users to login.

A reason not to enable/pre-configure any firewall is of course that it is not a requirement in many deployment scenario's and an image provides the most flexibility when people only need to **add what they need** rather than also remove what they don't...

Comment: Then why is iptables installed when centos switched to firewalld.

Comment: Firewalld is just a front end to iptables/netfilter. @SaadMasood

Comment: So there are iptables commandline program, iptables service and firewalld service, ufw etc. only iptables commandline program talks to netfilter kernel module, all others are just configuration tools. Though when firewalld is installed it takes precedence over all other tools even iptables commandline program.